# How to specify explicit equality in Coq search patterns?

Tags: coq

Suppose we have a hypothesis `x - x = 0`.

One would presume a theorem for this already exists, so we fire up `SearchAbout (_ - _ = 0)`. In this case however, we actually know that these underscores are equivalent. As such, I would prefer to write something like `SearchAbout (fun a => a - a = 0)` or something along those lines.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to import the `Arith` module (or a module supporting reasoning with the kind of numbers you'd like to deal with):

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
```

Then `Search (?x - ?x = 0).` will return

> `Nat.sub_diag: forall n : nat, n - n = 0`

You can also more concisely search for a relevant rewriting lemma with `SearchRewrite (?x - ?x).` (note that you only need to specify one side of the equality).

By the way, the `SearchAbout` command is deprecated.

Comment: Oooo, so `?x - ?x` is the secret sauce! Thank you! (Also, should I just use `Search` then?)

Comment: Also, interestingly enough, Coq doesn't define this as a group inverse - with neutral 0? So there's like a separate one for reals and nats and such?

Comment: I don't follow, sorry -- nats form a monoid under addition, but not a group.

Comment: Oh, I am an idiot, I wanted to say integers. It seems there are literally some R_ and Z_ versions of things, as opposed to just more general instances of some structure :(.

Comment: Yes, I don't recall any group structures in the stdlib of vanilla Coq.

Comment: Abelian groups ("Z-modules") are defined by some Coq libraries, for example math-comp https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.algebra.ssralg.html or math classes https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes/blob/master/theory/groups.v